# I cannot convert String into char array in VC++ 2010

Tags: c++-cli

I am trying Caesar cipher program in VC++. 
I tried converting `String` into char array.. but it is displaying `true` when  I display it..

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e){        
    System::String^ plain=(textBox1->Text);
    int i,j;
    char* msg = (char*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(plain).ToPointer();     
    int length=strlen(msg);

    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(msg[i]))
        {
            msg[i]=tolower(msg[i]);
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                if(msg[i]=='z')
                {
                    msg[i]='a';
                }
                else
                {
                    msg[i]++;
                }
            }
        }
     }    

    label3->Text=System::Convert::ToString(msg);
}
```

Comment: 1. Your code is leaking memory. 2. String marshaling in this direction is done with [`marshal_context`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx). 3. You don't need marshaling in the first place, just use a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation:

```
static String^ CaesarCipher(String^ input, int shift)
{
    const int numLetters = 'z' - 'a' + 1;
    shift = shift % numLetters;

    auto sb = gcnew System::Text::StringBuilder(input->Length);

    for each (auto c in input)
    {
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
        {
            c += shift;

            if (c > 'z')
                c -= numLetters;
            else if (c < 'a')
                c += numLetters;
        }
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        {
            c += shift;

            if (c > 'Z')
                c -= numLetters;
            else if (c < 'A')
                c += numLetters;
        }

        sb->Append(c);
    }

    return sb->ToString();
}
```

See? There's no need for marshaling at all since you're not calling into native code.

Your original code was leaking memory because you called `Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi` without calling `Marshal::FreeHGlobal`:

> `StringToHGlobalAnsi` is useful for custom marshaling or when mixing managed and unmanaged code. Because this method allocates the unmanaged memory required for a string, **always free the memory by calling `FreeHGlobal`**. `StringToHGlobalAnsi` provides the opposite functionality of `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`.

This should be automatic in your mind: when you allocate unmanaged memory, you're responsible of freeing it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. 
change in just one line made the miracle.

Change this line

**label3->Text=System::Convert::ToString(msg);** into

**label3->Text=gcnew String(msg,0,100);**

Comment: ya.. but i couldn't get you. Could you please tell me how a string can be converted into char without marshaling?  and Please tell me how did you find my code is leaking memory? Sorry I m new to coding.

Comment: I provided an answer to explain this.